# Error 500 when trying to contact server.js to send email

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to deploy an angular 7 website that uses nodemailer to send receive emails but keep getting error 500 internal server error.

The angular side of the bunch works fine but i can't seem to figure out how to run the node server on the web (I realize this might be a dumb question but forgive me I am a newbie)

This is my contact us service

```
  url: string = "/send";  //THIS MIGHT BE A PROBLEM

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  sendMessage(messageContent: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(messageContent), {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }),
      responseType: "text"
    });
```

And this is my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  provider: "gmail",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: "an email",
    pass: "a password"
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.post("/send", function(req, res) {
  let senderName = req.body.name;
  let senderEmail = req.body.email;
  let messageSubject = req.body.subject;
  let messageText = req.body.message;
  let copyToSender = req.body.contactFormCopy;

  let mailOptions = {
    to: ["anemail"],
    from: senderName,
    subject: messageSubject,
    text: messageText,
    replyTo: senderEmail
  };

  if (senderName === "") {
    res.status(400);
    res.send({
      message: "Bad request"
    });
    return;
  }

  if (senderEmail === "") {
    res.status(400);
    res.send({
      message: "Bad request"
    });
    return;
  }

  if (messageSubject === "") {
    res.status(400);
    res.send({
      message: "Bad request"
    });
    return;
  }

  if (messageText === "") {
    res.status(400);
    res.send({
      message: "Bad request"
    });
    return;
  }

  if (copyToSender) {
    mailOptions.to.push(senderEmail);
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.end("error");
    } else {
      console.log("Message sent: ", response);
      res.end("sent");
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Express started on port: ", port);
});
```

Comment: What is the actual error you see in Node js logs ?

Comment: @dota2pro it's literally just 500(Internal server error)

Comment: @user76706055 he meant the logs of the server, "500" is just an error the client reports because the server wouldn't actually tell it what is the problem. When you run your node server, you should be able to see the logs. Perhaps there was an exception or some other error?

Comment: @ShacharHar-Shuv ahh i don&#39;t know how to run the server online that was part of my question :(

Comment: @user76706055 Perhaps I didn't understand you properly. You're saying that this works locally, but when you try to deploy the server, it doesn't? When deploying web apps, you need to deploy the server side and client side separately. I guess your problem is with sending the request to the right origin. Angular has a feature called "proxy request" just for that.

Comment: @ShacharHar-Shuv I will try it out thank you very much!

Comment: @ShacharHar-Shuv Sorry to disturb you but when you said i should deploy them separately did you mean i should upload the website files and then upload the server.js file to the same public html folder? because when i compile for prod the server gets complied with them.

Comment: @user76706055 I was merely stating common practice. Perhaps you did it a different way (one server for both backend and front-end). Usually most apps have a separate server for each.